# UITextField not appearing in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, uitextfield

So I recently made an app for iOS 6 that reads PDF's. It worked fine on my iPhone 3GS, however when I recompiled it for iOS 8 in a newer version of Xcode (originally using 4.5, now using 6.01) the text field for entering the name of the PDF you wanted to load no longer appears where it should.

The Text Field in question appeared inside an alert box when the user pressed open.

Heres the code for it that worked in iOS 6

```
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Please enter a valid PDF name below:" message:@"(Please add .PDF on the end!) \n \n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    textField.delegate = nil;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.placeholder = @"PDF name";
    textField.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0/255.0f green:98.0/255.0f blue:98.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert; //set up an alert box with a text feild
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addSubview:textField];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Comment: In your case is to set alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput; This will add a text field for you. You can access it in the UIAlertView delegate callback by using UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code!!

```
    UIAlertController * alertView=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please enter a valid PDF name below:"
                                      message:@"Please add .PDF on the end!"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertView addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"PDF name";

    }];

    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    //Handel your yes please button action here
                                    UITextField *textField = alertView.textFields[0];
                                    NSString *pdfName = textField.text;
                                    NSLog(@"PDF Name: %@",pdfName);
                                    [alertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


                                }];
    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   //Handel no, thanks button
                                   [alertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];

    [alertView addAction:yesButton];
    [alertView addAction:noButton];
    [self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
```